# A question about the use of 4017 and ULN2003A

Tags: pic, 7segmentdisplay, pic16f, cd4017

[image: the electrical circuit]

Can someone please help me understand the use of CD4017 AND ULN2003A with the 7-segment display?

Comment: Did you try reading the datasheet? Usually page one of all datasheets gives you the overview and features of these devices. What specifically don't you understand that the datasheet doesn't tell you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This driving method is called "multiplexed driving". Only one display shows (displays) data at a time and switches to the next one. This repeats fast enough to give the impression that all of the displays are "on" at the same time.

---

The segment data is common for all displays which appear to be common-cathode:

[image]

[*Img Src*](https://electrocredible.com/7-segment-display-with-raspberry-pi-pico/)

The segment data for each display is generated by the MCU and transferred to the displays using 74HCT4511 through 220R series (current limiting) resistors and then the respective display is selected whilst the rest are un-selected using ULN2003A.

ULN2003A can be thought of as a low-side switch: If you apply a positive voltage to, say, pin 1B then the pin 1C will connect to the ground. Likewise, if you apply to the pin 1B zero volts then 1C will become floating. For example, if you load the segment data and apply 3V to the 1B pin of the ULN2003A (also apply zero to the other inputs) then the data will be displayed on the 2nd digit of A2. Likewise, if you load another data to the segments and apply 3V to the 2B input then the data will be displayed on the 1st digit of A1.

The inputs (1B ... 4B) of the ULN2003A come from 4017 which is a counter, so every time a segment data is displayed on one display the next display is selected in the next `CLK` pulse. After the last display shows its data, the counter is reset to zero using the MR pin and the cycle starts afresh.

Comment: thanks a lot but i still don't understand the purpose behind using 4017 , is it because we need to to display on every rising edge ?

Comment: @AbirElAbdellaoui I didn't check the datasheet if it's on the rising or falling edge. All I can say is that the 4017 is there to "select" the next digit to display the data on. It could be maybe within a few clock pulses, or every pulse, I don't know. Please read the datasheet.